# Why those two IP not pinging?

Tags: subnet

[See this image, Before you go for question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaYez.png) Here, 8.0.0.1/8 pinging with 192.168.1.1/24 but 8.0.0.2/5 don't ping with 192.168.1.1/24. Could anyone say me, What actual problem?

Comment: Question should be asked on network engineering stack exchange. Also, when asking such a question you should provide details like: "how do you know that they are not communicating" - because from the green lights we can clearly see that the interfaces are UP. Please be more concrete, in life and in SO.

Comment: can you provide context with a network diagram please (router, switch, hosts, servers)?

Comment: Put your first computer in the same subnet of `/5`. Both PC should be able to ping that interface.

Answer (score 0):

8.0.0.1/8 and 8.0.0.2./5 overlap, messing up the routing. Each router interface requires a distinct network address.